# angular interfaces with concrete implementations

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface in angular2 typescript which has some fields and some methods with signature only. I need to have a method with a body in interface
Can there be some methods with implementation inside the angular2 typescript interfaces?

Comment: There can be no interface which includes implementation. Perhaps you need an abstract class.

Comment: No, interfaces have no implementation.

Comment: An interface is a contract, not an implementation. By definition an interface can never contain an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a base class that implements the interface or an abstract class.